# Andoid WebView работа в фоновом режиме

Tags: android, webview, android-service, android-webview

Всем привет. Я пока что новичок в Android
Я создал Android приложение которое работает на WebView. Использую Service для работы в фоновом режиме. Когда открываю приложение происходит передача данных на JS.Стоит только свернуть приложение как JS код не передаёт данных и не обновляет местоположение в базу данных.

Вот что мне удалось написать:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68967162/webview-service-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23674635/16266470 создать вебвью внутри самого сервиса.

Comment: Эмми, я эту ссылку читал и изучал 1000000 раз и мне помогло. Поэтому и моя ссылка указана с кодом, что бы мне подсказали мб я где-то ошибся

Comment: тогда почему у вас вебВью создана в активити, а не в сервисе, как рекомендуется в том треде?

Comment: если я правильно понял, то вы хотите получать местоположения пользователя в фоновом режиме?

Comment: Да все верно, приложение должно работать в фоновом режиме, и через JS обновлять его через каждые 15 минут. С Frontend стороны нет проблем, а вот с передачей данных в фоновом режиме в Android есть ( используя WebView

Comment: а как вы получаете геолокацию пользователя? p.s. используйте пометку @ИмяУчастника чтобы приходило оповещение

Comment: Спасибо @Wlad я использую JS код который загружает WebView страницу index.php

Comment: ну это неправильно. если хотите получать данные в Android вам нужен Location. а для того, чтобы это было в фоне - Foreground Location. гуглите в сторону Foreground Location Service